# Forms Based Authentication SharePoint 2010 using SSRS HTML viewer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I'm running SSRS in integrated mode (Trusted) and have an issue with trying to use the HTML viewer on a Forms Based Authentication site in Sharepoint 2010.  I have found several articles on using the report viewer in FBA; however, to the best of my knowledge, I need to use the HTML viewer as the ultimate goal is to seamlessly produce a PDF file for the end user. The error I'm getting is "401 UNAUTHORIZED An unknown error occurred with the Reporting Services endpoint on this SharePoint site." The Url format I'm submitting is as follows: 
http:///_vti_bin/ReportServer?//.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF.  Some additional information, the request works if I use the default site name and not the forms based name.

So my question is twofold, should I be able to do this in FBA? and if not what is the best route to produce a PDF of the report for the client?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure you've already done this but make sure that the users have access to the server that the ssrs report is on.

Comment: Thanks, we are running the connection to the SSRS server as trusted.  I thought that would handle any permissions issues with requests, is that not the case?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, running SSRS with SharePoint is tricky. For SSRS to be able to receive the user credential, it has to be running in kerberos mode. Otherwise, the request to SSRS is made as ANONYMUS LOGON (that's why you are getting a 401).

Now, for the PDF, you have a few options :

1. Call the SSRS webservice directly and produce a PDF.
2. Setup a subscription and generate it as PDF, either to filesystem, email, etc.
3. Do what you are doing now, but with kerberos enabled.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I decided to go the route of trying the web service yesterday, I'm having some difficulty with the loading of the report.  I'm getting the following error: The value of parameter 'UserToken' is not valid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InvalidParameterException:  I'm calling the Load report method as follows -  rs.LoadReport(trusteduserHeader, reportPath, historyID, out serviceInfo, out execInfo); I have added the service account's user token to the trusted header as well.  Any suggestions??  Thanks...